# Generating a variable number of random numbers to a list, then comparing those numbers to a target?

Tags: c#

How would I go about generating a serializable variable of random numbers to a list, then comparing those generated numbers to a target number?

What I want to do is make a program that takes in a number, such as 42, and generates that number of random numbers to a list while still keeping the original variable, in this case 42, to be referenced later. Super ham-handed pseudo-code(?) example:

```
public class Generate {
[SerializeField]
int generate = 42;

List<int> results = new List<int>;

    public void Example() {
        int useGenerate = generate;
        //Incoming pseudo-code (rather, code that I don't know how to do, exactly)
        while (useGenerate => 1) {
            results.add (random.range(0,100)); //Does this make a number between 0 and 99?
            int useGenerate = useGenerate - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I think this will do something to that effect, once I figure out how to actually code it properly (Still learning).

From there, I'd like to compare the list of results to a target number, to see how many of them pass a certain threshold, in this case greater than or equal to 50. I assume this would require a "foreach" thingamabobber, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that, really. With each "success", I'd like to increment a variable to be returned at a later point. I guess something like this:

```
int success = 50;
int target = 0;

foreach int in List<results> {
    if (int => success) {
        int target = target + 1;
    }
}
```

If I have the right idea, please just teach me how to properly code it. If you have any suggestions on how to improve it (like the whole ++ and -- thing I see here and there but don't know how to use), please teach me that, too. I looked around the web for using foreach with lists and it seemed really complicated and people were seemingly pulling some new bit of information from the Aether to include in the operation. Thanks for reading, and thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: `just teach me how to...` this is not a tutorial site - read [ask] and take the [tour].  Maybe do a `thingamabobber` search afterwards

Comment: I realize this isn't a tutorial site, but when I searched for how to do it there weren't any good tutorials that I saw or I wouldn't ask here.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Role-playing game aid. The potential is quite endless there.